# Kendo Angular2 UI Dropdownlist Module not working

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am rolling out KendoUI for Angular2 on a project and want to user their dropdownlist module.  I installed it via npm using the command:

```
npm install --save @progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns
```

I then imported it into my module by

```
import { DropDownsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';
```

I also dropped it into the imports array.  However, now when I use Gulp and Webpack to build I get a slew of errors like

> Duplicate identifier 'readonly'

on a whole bunch of components.  I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, making sure to remove it from my *package.json* file and making sure it was deleted from the *node_modules* folder.  Anyone else seeing issues with this module?  Has anyone gotten it to work properly, or is this an issue with a new build?  I have several other of their modules working just fine.

Comment: Doh!  That totally fixed it.  Thanks Sanket!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid `Duplicate identifier 'readonly'` issue with KendoUI-angular2,

you should use `"typescript": "^2.0.0"` version with angular2 `2.0.0` version.